# problem configure JBoss to work with JNDI

Tags: java, jboss, jndi

I am trying to bind connection to the DB using JNDI in my application that runs on JBoss. I did the following:

1. I created the datasource file **oracle-ds.xml** filled it with the relevant xml elements:

> ```
> <datasources>
>    <local-tx-datasource>
>      <jndi-name>bilby</jndi-name>
>      ...
>     </local-tx-datasource>
> </datasources>
> ```

and put it in the folder \server\default\deploy

2. Added the relevant oracle jar file
3. than in my application I performed:

> JndiObjectFactoryBean factory = new
>        JndiObjectFactoryBean();
>
> ```
>  factory.setJndiName("bilby");
>  try{
>      factory.afterPropertiesSet();
>      dataSource = factory.getObject();
>  }
>  catch(NamingException ne) {
>      ne.printStackTrace();
>  }
> ```

and this cause the error:

> javax.naming.NameNotFoundException:
>   bilby not bound

then in the output **after this error occured** I saw the line:

> 18:37:56,560 INFO 
>   [ConnectionFactoryBindingService]
>   Bound ConnectionManager 'jb
>   oss.jca:service=DataSourceBinding,name=bilby'
>   to JNDI name 'java:bilby'

So what is my configuration problem? I think that it may be that JBoss first loads and runs the .war file of my application and only then it loads the oracle-ds.xml that contain my data-source definition.
The problem is that they are both located in the same folder. 
Is there a way to define priority of loading them, or maybe this is not the problem at all.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use such construction to call Datasource: java:bilby.

You can read more about that here:

[Naming and Directory (JNDI) - JBOSS jndi Datasource: jdbc not bound](http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=626778)

Comment: I tried the suggestion from both answers.
I looked at the list() print from the jmx-console and saw that 'bilby' is registered under java:Namespace.
I tried to call this connection by:
factory.setJndiName("java:bilby"); 
factory.setJndiName("java/bilby"); 
factory.setJndiName("jdbc/bilby"); 
But none of them managed to find the jndi resource!
Any other suggestions?

Comment: See continuation of this tread at:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2843218/problem-configure-jboss-to-work-with-jndi2

Comment: Maybe you can check if your connection exits in JNDI tree. You can use twiddle command or jmx-console. Here you have example how to use twiddle:

twiddle.sh invoke jboss:service=JNDIView list true

If you have secure jmx-console you should pass credential using -u or -p parameters. If your server is running somewhere else that localhost you should also set -s parameter.

PS. Sorry for answering here, but I cannot add comments on your new thread and I am pretty sure that it is not an answer :)

Comment: This is part of the frustration - that I see the datasource exist in the Tree. I run JBoss locally on my machine and I am able to see it through the JBoss web-console.
It's under System-->JMX Mbeans --> jboss.jdbc-->jboss.jdbc:service=metadata,datasource=bilby
the stateString of it is 'Started'
so it seems that it's up and running only I can't approach it from my application )-:

Comment: I forgot to mention that I am working with JBoss version 4.2.3.GA

Comment: OK, this is the correct answer in normal cases. the Datasource is by 'java:<jndi-name>' In my specific case I have got conflicts between JBoss jars in my WEB-INF/lib to jars of JBoss server that cause JNDI to work improperly.

Answer (score 0):

To check how the datasource is bound in the JNDI tree you should use the `jmx-console`
http://localhost8080/jmx-console/HtmlAdaptor?action=inspectMBean&name=jboss%3Aservice%3DJNDIView
and invoke the `list()` method.

**Datasources are registered under "jdbc". In your case "jdbc/bilby"**

EDIT: That was an example that works for me without spring.
Now  found this [example](http://www.torsten-horn.de/techdocs/jee-spring-db-tx.htm) which injects a more complete JNDI name.

```
<bean id="idDataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/bilby" />
</bean>
```