# JNDI binding in JBoss (LiveCycle turnkey)

Tags: java, jndi, livecycle, jboss-4.2.x

I am using Adobe LiveCycle ES 2 turnkey project, which runs on JBoss AS 4.2.1.GA. I am having a problem getting a JNDI binding to work in JBoss. It seems eerily similar to an earlier post, [problem configure JBoss to work with JNDI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2828237/problem-configure-jboss-to-work-with-jndi), but I certainly have found no solution.

This is my setup. I have a -ds.xml file in place:

```
C:\Adobe\Adobe LiveCycle ES2\jboss\server\lc_turnkey\deploy\rmb-ds.xml
```

The contents of that file are as follows:

```
<datasources>
   <local-tx-datasource>
      <jndi-name>RMB_DS</jndi-name>
      <connection-url>jdbc:sqlserver://localhost\SQLEXPRESS;DatabaseName=rmb</connection-url>
      <driver-class>com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</driver-class>
      <user-name>sa</user-name>
      <password>password</password>
      <check-valid-connection-sql>SELECT 1 FROM sysobjects</check-valid-connection-sql>
      <!-- corresponding type-mapping in the standardjbosscmp-jdbc.xml (optional) -->
      <metadata>
         <type-mapping>MS SQLSERVER2000</type-mapping>
      </metadata>
   </local-tx-datasource>
</datasources>
```

I have a Java project, whose /RMB/WebContent/WEB-INF/web.xml contains the following:

```
<resource-ref>
    <description>DB Connection</description>
    <res-ref-name>java:RMB_DS</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

Now, every time I deploy the WAR, it fails with the following error:

```
2011-09-06 15:44:17,786 ERROR [org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer] Could not start deployment: file:/C:/Adobe/Adobe LiveCycle ES2/jboss/server/lc_turnkey/deploy/RMB.war
org.jboss.deployment.DeploymentException: Error during deploy; - nested throwable: (javax.naming.NamingException: resource-ref: java:RMB_DS has no valid JNDI binding. Check the jboss-web/resource-ref.)
    at org.jboss.web.AbstractWebDeployer.start(AbstractWebDeployer.java:384)
...
Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: resource-ref: java:RMB_DS has no valid JNDI binding. Check the jboss-web/resource-ref.
    at org.jboss.web.AbstractWebDeployer.linkResourceRefs(AbstractWebDeployer.java:623)
```

I am 100% positive that the JNDI binding itself is correct. I can see the following in web console > System > JMX Beans > jboss.jdbc > jboss.jdbc:service=metadata,datasource=RMB_DS

```
MBean Name: Domain Name:    jboss.jdbc
service:    metadata
datasource: RMB_DS
MBean Java Class:   org.jboss.ejb.plugins.cmp.jdbc.metadata.DataSourceMetaData
```

Also, using LiveCycle workbench I can make a process that hits this service and runs some SQL against datasource java:/RMB_DS..

SO, there has to be something wrong with my WAR or web.xml right? Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Ketan, who is awesome!

Needed a jboss-web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-web>
    <resource-ref>
        <res-ref-name>RMB_DS</res-ref-name>
        <jndi-name>java:/RMB_DS</jndi-name>
    </resource-ref>
</jboss-web>
```

And changed the original web.xml to have:

```
<resource-ref>
   <description>DB Connection</description>
   <res-ref-name>RMB_DS</res-ref-name>
   <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
   <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

Which matches rmb-ds.xml

```
<datasources>
   <local-tx-datasource>
      <jndi-name>RMB_DS</jndi-name>
      <connection-url>jdbc:sqlserver://localhost\SQLEXPRESS;DatabaseName=RMB</connection-url>
      <driver-class>com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</driver-class>
      <user-name>sa</user-name>
      <password>password</password>
      <check-valid-connection-sql>SELECT 1 FROM sysobjects</check-valid-connection-sql>
      <!-- corresponding type-mapping in the standardjbosscmp-jdbc.xml (optional) -->
      <metadata>
         <type-mapping>MS SQLSERVER2000</type-mapping>
      </metadata>
   </local-tx-datasource>
</datasources>
```